# Sentences alignment error with the lettrine package

Tags: line-spacing, letterspacing, lettrine

I want to align the two starting words in two sentences with each other ('ROM' in the first line with 'may' in the second line)

[image]

How could I do that? Here is the working code:

```
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=2]{\textbf{F}}{rom} they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw  mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient not. Letter of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable surprise screened no up as.

\end{document}
```

After using the fix-cm package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[lines=2]{\textbf{F}}{rom} they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw  mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient not. Letter of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable surprise screened no up as.
  \end{document}
```

[image]

But still two words (ROM and Improving) are not aligned.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{fix-cm}` in your document?

Comment: Your document is incomplete, if I add `\documentclass{article} the F is correctly aligned. also your image appears double spaced. Please post the image made from running the code as posted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I have \documentclass{report}

Answer (score 5):

In order to work, `lettrine` needs a set of fully scalable fonts. The default Computer Modern aren't, for historical reasons.

You can make them fully scalable by loading `fix-cm`

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % should be here
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt} % read the doc about it
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lines=2]{\textbf{F}}{rom} they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw
mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept
very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient
not. Letter of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable
surprise screened no up as.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, add `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: but 'ROM' and 'proving' are not aligned

Comment: @Harry That's another problem. I'll add how to cope with it.

Answer (score 2):

You should also use the provided `\LettrineFontHook` to specify the series for the dropped capital, I think. That is, my solution is very like [egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219024/) but with that one difference:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\bfseries}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
  \lettrine[lines=2]{F}{rom} they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw  mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient not. Letter of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable surprise screened no up as.
\end{document}
```

[image: Aligned lettrine]

Comment: Is there anyway we can use simple characters after the big capital letter as an example 'rom' instead of 'ROM'?

Comment: @Harry You can use `\renewcommand\LettrineTextFont{\normalfont}` but it will not look right IMHO.