# Problem with drop cap letterine command

Tags: lettrine

Problem with drop cap `\letterine`.

Hi, I am trying to use drop cap in Latex-Texmaker using the Letterine command but the cap letter is not aligned within the paragraph

[image]

, as you can see it is sitting alone outside the paragraph. I think I am missing something there, any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\Letterine{F}{ibre} metal laminates....

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's strange, no `\Lettrine` command exists. You must have defined it somewhere and not telling us about it. Can you provide the community with a *complete*, minimal example that replicates the problem

Comment: Firstly, the command is `\lettrine` and not `\Letterine`. As written your example does not compile. After fixing that error, the code compiles with the expected output with the top of `F` lined up with the paragraph.

Comment: Looking at your sample output, do you perhaps have loaded `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}`? The line gap between the first two lines are unnaturally large. In any case, this is discussed also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219023/sentences-alignment-error-with-the-lettrine-package try loading `\usepackage{lmodern}` which should fix the font scaling issue.

Answer (score 2):

The command is `\lettrine`. See below MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[findent=2pt,nindent=0pt]{F}{ibre} metal laminates test test
test test test test test test
test test test test test test
test test test test test test
test test test test test test

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]